# Webpage with a Dynamic Header

Tags: xml, xslt, header

I have a webpage with a dynamic list. I want the headers to be configurable. To start with the headers are named as `column1`, `column2`, ... `columnnN`. Clicking on any of these header I open up a DHTML modal window where I select the header name from a predefined list so that I can assign this header name to the selected column. So I am returning a unique ID from my modal window to my parent form. Now i want to change the header to the selected header.

My XML:

```xml
<ROOT>
    <Header><Item>Column 1</Item></Header>
    <Header><Item>Column 2</Item></Header>

    <ROW>
        <COlUMN>Zamora</COlUMN>
        <COlUMN> Ruby E.</COlUMN>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <COlUMN>Hatfield</COlUMN>
        <COlUMN> Hanae B.</COlUMN>
    </ROW>
</ROOT>
```

Here is how I am generating the XML in the code-behind:

```javascript
oXMLString.Append(Chr(13) & "<Header>")
oXMLString.Append(Chr(13) & "<Item>Column " & j + 1 & "</Item>")
oXMLString.Append(Chr(13) & "</Header>")
```

Here is my xslt for the header:

```xml
<tr class="thead">
    <xsl:for-each select="Header/Item">        
        <td class="rowHead" style="vertical-align:bottom;">
            <a href="#">
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
                    <xsl:text>showPopWin('UploadFile_Step4_Modal.aspx',500,500,returnFieldID);</xsl:text>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </a>
        </td>
    </xsl:for-each>
</tr>
```

When the list is generated the column headers are `column1` and `column2` where n=2

In the xslt the `onclick` event open a modal window which returns a `fieldID` for the column header.

Now suppose i click on `column1` and the modal window returns `fieldid="1"` which is predefined in the database, how do i change the column header from
`column1` to `Firstname` (`Fieldid=1` is `Firstname`)

Comment: please edit your question s.t. the markup is displayed correctly

Comment: You need to enclose your XML and XSLT in backticks in order for them to be visible here.  Until you do, there's no way anyone can answer this question.

Comment: This was my first post..hence I didn't knew. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need xslt to solve your problem. All you need is some JavaScript. Here is a sample code in jQuery:

```
$('td.rowHead a').click(function(){
    var fieldId, fieldName;
    fieldId = // get field id from the popup
    fieldName = // get field name (e.g. via AJAX)
    this.innerHTML = fieldName;
});
```